# Renumbering a List using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list powered by jQuery UI's [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) that allows a user to order line items. I want to have a number that represents the position of that object after it is dropped.

```
<ul>
     <li><span class="number">1</span> Apple</li>
     <li><span class="number">2</span> Microsoft</li>
     <li><span class="number">3</span> Canonical</li>
<ul>
```

Right now I have a number (not using an `<ol>` because I want to style/position the number... and that wouldn't solve the problem anyway). Obviously, if I were to move Canonical's line item to the top, the 3 would stay with it.

Is there  way, using jQuery that I could recalculate the numbers every time a line item is dropped in place?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shorter:

```
$('li > span.number').each(function(i) {
   $(this).text(i+1);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`index()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/index)+1 (or equivalent way of calculating an index) of the `<li>` in the parent. Something like

```
$('li > span.number').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this); 
   $this.text($this.parent('li').prevAll().length + 1);
});
```

Here's a [**Working Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ucubi3). Add */edit* to the URL to see the code

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm! :)

Comment: +1 for providing the demo, helpful to see it all fit together